# Error Running label_image After Building TensorFlow Lite: tensorflow_src/tensorf low/lite/util.cc BytesRequired number of elements overflowed

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I built TensorFlow Lite following: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake on x86_64 in Ubuntu 22.4

The compiler version is

```
$ cc --version
cc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
```

I tried to run

```
tflite_build/examples/label_image/label_image \
  --tflite_model=mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tflite \
  --labels=labels_mobilenet_quant_v1_224.txt \
  --image=label_image_test.jpg
```

The tflite file is obtained from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/image_classification/overview. The direct link is https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant_and_labels.zip

Output:

```
INFO: Loaded model mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tflite
INFO: resolved reporter
INFO: Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
INFO: Applying 1 TensorFlow Lite delegate(s) lazily.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
VERBOSE: Replacing 29 out of 31 node(s) with delegate (TfLiteXNNPackDelegate) no
de, yielding 4 partitions for the whole graph.
INFO: Successfully applied the default TensorFlow Lite delegate indexed at 0.
 *NOTE*: because a delegate has been applied, the precision of computations shou
ld be unchanged, but the exact output tensor values may have changed. If such ou
tput values are checked in your code, like in your tests etc., please consider i
ncreasing error tolerance for the check.
ERROR: xxx/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/util.cc BytesRequired number of elements overflowed.
```

Eventually, the program seg faults, not surprisingly.

I can run this below without error:

```
tflite_build/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model --graph=mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tflite
```

Output:

```
INFO: STARTING!
WARN: Duplicate flags: num_threads
INFO: Log parameter values verbosely: [0]
INFO: Graph: [mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tflite]
INFO: Loaded model mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tflite
INFO: Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
INFO: Applying 1 TensorFlow Lite delegate(s) lazily.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
VERBOSE: Replacing 29 out of 31 node(s) with delegate (TfLiteXNNPackDelegate) node, yielding 4 partitions for the whole graph.
INFO: Successfully applied the default TensorFlow Lite delegate indexed at 0.
 *NOTE*: because a delegate has been applied, the precision of computations should be unchanged, but the exact output tensor values may have changed. If such output values are checked in your code, like in your tests etc., please consider increasing error tolerance for the check.
INFO: The input model file size (MB): 4.27635
INFO: Initialized session in 39.149ms.
INFO: Running benchmark for at least 1 iterations and at least 0.5 seconds but terminate if exceeding 150 seconds.
INFO: count=3 first=217309 curr=196488 min=196488 max=217309 avg=203436 std=9809

INFO: Running benchmark for at least 50 iterations and at least 1 seconds but terminate if exceeding 150 seconds.
INFO: count=50 first=198013 curr=192898 min=191722 max=200007 avg=195195 std=2153

INFO: Inference timings in us: Init: 39149, First inference: 217309, Warmup (avg): 203436, Inference (avg): 195195
INFO: Note: as the benchmark tool itself affects memory footprint, the following is only APPROXIMATE to the actual memory footprint of the model at runtime. Take the information at your discretion.
INFO: Memory footprint delta from the start of the tool (MB): init=11 overall=14.125
```

I can use the same tflite file and jpg file using the official python module successfully.

What's wrong?

I did notice this suspicious setting:

```
struct Settings {
  bool verbose = false;
  bool accel = false;
  TfLiteType input_type = kTfLiteFloat32;
```

I believe the model is in uint8. I modified it to use kTfLiteUint8. No difference was observed. There is no cmdline arg to change this setting. Not important?

I also don't see any obvious branch that can disable xnnpack completely. It seems to be the only implementation for the pure CPU based engine.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the image file input accepts bitmap file only. Moreover, the format must be a very simple one as my earlier attempt to convert .jpg to .bmp using tools produced other errors on channel sizes. The simplicity of file format is evident after reading the file parsing code in tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image/bitmap_helpers.cc.

I found that the default bmp test file is available in the repo as tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image/testdata/grace_hopper.bmp. Using that file yields successful output.

```
<cut>
INFO: 0.796078: 653 military uniform
INFO: 0.0901961: 907 Windsor tie
INFO: 0.0156863: 458 bow tie
INFO: 0.0117647: 466 bulletproof vest
INFO: 0.00392157: 922 book jacket
```

The full working verbose output is stored here for reference: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VzUpTtTr4FHqUrrZY0diSDn7wFjp8GaPmlLjbDJ-EMY/edit?usp=sharing

For reference, the failing verbose output is stored here for reference: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1klQ54PqmHZaE4K8zUlGmFR8GMai6jHJ5E2VuRW32hnQ/edit?usp=sharing

I can speculate that the tensor/node output shows the active inference progress, not just the interpretation of .tffile alone. Any error one may face is highly dependent on the graph input file.